# Permission Errors (403) on Apps Script :run

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I have created a standalone script that fills a row in a spreadsheet, creates folder and copies files to the created folder. Executing the script from the script editor result in flawless results.
I have published the script as deploy as API executable. I am using the OAuth 2.0 Playground to try and execute the script as follows:

- Step 1 Select & authorize APIs
  Apps Script API v1 (all listed scopes)
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
  When prompted enter my email address and allow playground access.
- Step 2 Exchange authorization code for tokens
  straightforward get the access and refresh tokens
- Step 3 Configure request to API
  request URI  https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/MYsYdLzLGi8kdH6eUzPre42EdFEUJsEaZ:run
  request body

  ```
  {
    "function": "testing",
    "devMode": false  //true results in same error
  }
  ```

Content-Type application/json

The complete exchange

POST /v1/scripts/MYsYdLzLGi8kdH6eUzPre42EdFEUJsEaZ:run HTTP/1.1
Host: script.googleapis.com
Content-length: 47
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer
ya29.GluWBSHT61M2b9qMSVG9WbxP2nTegbnrLTCz_jWRZsMTd1iF5672PxceRhzamw8Hbs1moKldYQPFAet-vD6d_fIFXeNfqyx7sFyD8YKKDI2rRy_bKA4epWya5b-V

```
{
  "function": "testing",
  "devMode": true
}
```

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-length: 126
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: ESF
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private
Date: Sat, 07 Apr 2018 13:22:48 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303432; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="42,41,39,35"
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", 
    "message": "The caller does not have permission", 
    "code": 403
  }
}
```

I am the caller, I am the owner of the script and the script is shared with anyone who has a link.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old, but just want to answer your for question for others to know.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run

> The error 403, PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
> indicates that the Cloud Platform project used to authorize the
> request is not the same as the one used by the script.

You have to set your Client ID and secret key here ( see attached image ).

[image]

To create those keys is a different topic but this will help guide you:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#creating_oauth_credentials